# procedure MySQL using concat

Tags: mysql, procedure, concatenation

Can you help me here?

```
BEGIN

set @currentdate=now();

set @formateddate=convert(date_format(@currentdate,'%Y%m%d'),char);

select @t;

drop table if exists CONCAT('account_class_',@formateddate) 

,CONCAT('class_courses_',@formateddate),CONCAT('student_',@formateddate),CONCAT(

'messages_',@formateddate),CONCAT('announcement_',@formateddate),CONCAT('student

_activity_',@formateddate),CONCAT('activity_',@formateddate),CONCAT('account_cla

ss_students_',@formateddate);

create table CONCAT('account_class_',@formateddate) select * from account_class;

create table CONCAT('class_courses_',@formateddate) select * from class_courses;

create table CONCAT('student_',@formateddate) select * from student;

create table CONCAT('messages_',@formateddate) select * from messages;

create table CONCAT('announcement_',@formateddate) select * from announcement;

create table CONCAT('student_activity_',@formateddate) select * from 

student_activity;

create table CONCAT('activity_',@formateddate) select * from activity;

create table CONCAT('account_class_students_',@formateddate) select * from 

account_class_students;


END
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What happens instead? Any error messages?

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('account_class_',@formateddate) ,CONCAT('class_courses_',@formateddate),CONCAT(' at line 11

Comment: i am trying to make producer that create backup

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to construct a table name.  That is not allowed.  In theory, you could use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql;

set @sql = replace('create table [table] select * from account_class',
                   [table], 'CONCAT('account_class_', @formateddate));

prepare x from @sql;

execute x;
```

However, I would discourage creating such a proliferation of tables, when simple views can do what you want (or just a `where` clause).